# How do I return the total of this object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to take the price and tax of these and return the total of everything. I'm learning so I apologize for the simple question.

```
const orders = [{"price":15,"tax":0.09},{"price":42,"tax":0.07},{"price":56,"tax":0.11},
{"price":80,"tax":0.11},{"price":69,"tax":0.06},{"price":68,"tax":0.14},
{"price":72,"tax":0.14},{"price":51,"tax":0.09},{"price":89,"tax":0.15},
{"price":48,"tax":0.13}];
// Do not edit code above.

/*
  Use a higher-order method to get the sum of all the order totals after adding in the sales tax
*/

var ordersTotal  = orders.reduce(function(total, num) {
    return total + num;
    })
  ordersTotal;
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does right now and why this isn't the desired output rather than just asking for an end result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give reduce something to start with, in this example `0` is probably a good start. Then each `num` passed to `reduce` will be an object. Currently you're just adding the object like `total = total + {"price":15,"tax":0.09}` and that doesn't work. You need to look at each property you want to add. It's not clear if tax is a percentage or a total amount. Below we'll just add it, but it should be clear how to add as a percentage if you want.

```js
const orders = [{"price":15,"tax":0.09},{"price":42,"tax":0.07},{"price":56,"tax":0.11},{"price":80,"tax":0.11},{"price":69,"tax":0.06},{"price":68,"tax":0.14},{"price":72,"tax":0.14},{"price":51,"tax":0.09},{"price":89,"tax":0.15},{"price":48,"tax":0.13}];

var ordersTotal  = orders.reduce(function(total, num) {
    return total + num.price + num.tax; // add properties
    }, 0) // start with 0

console.log(ordersTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Description). And please make sure to pass `0` as the initial value to your reduce function.

```js
const orders = [{"price":15,"tax":0.09},{"price":42,"tax":0.07},{"price":56,"tax":0.11},{"price":80,"tax":0.11},{"price":69,"tax":0.06},{"price":68,"tax":0.14},{"price":72,"tax":0.14},{"price":51,"tax":0.09},{"price":89,"tax":0.15},{"price":48,"tax":0.13}];

const result = orders.reduce((a,{price,tax})=>a+price+tax,0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start with a zero so it doesn't try to coerce the result into a string.

```js
const orders = [{"price":15,"tax":0.09},{"price":42,"tax":0.07},{"price":56,"tax":0.11},
{"price":80,"tax":0.11},{"price":69,"tax":0.06},{"price":68,"tax":0.14},
{"price":72,"tax":0.14},{"price":51,"tax":0.09},{"price":89,"tax":0.15},
{"price":48,"tax":0.13}];
// Do not edit code above.
 
var ordersTotal  = orders.reduce(function(total, order) {
    return total + order.price + order.tax;
    },0)
console.log(ordersTotal,ordersTotal.toFixed(2))
```